# "if I do this will I get this result?" type of questions

Tags: discussion

Every once in a while I come across questions like "If I do this, will I get this result?". The recent example is:

[Signing Powershell Script with External CA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432860/signing-powershell-script-with-external-ca)

I'm always not sure what to do with these questions. One of the best advices that I took on at SO is "if you don't know what to do, just do nothing. move on". However keeping in mind that we are trying to help people get answers here, I keep wondering.

*Some* questions of this type can be answered with "No, this will not work because...". Some of them can be answered with "Yes, I tried it and it worked for me" or "Yes, this is how this thing is commonly accomplished". But there are also questions that the best answer is "you have to try that and see if it works. It looks like it should work, but there is no way to know without trying".

The latter type is sometimes hard to determine, because it depends on the experience of the reader. With the question that I linked I do believe that it's hard to give a definite answer here, but I can easily be wrong. It's possible that someone comes around and says that this is exactly how it's done and that this will always work. It's even possible that *many* people will do that.

So my question is, how one should deal with this type of questions. Is the best course of action is to just move on and leave it for others to chime in, or is there anything else that can be done to help the poster?

Answer (score 4):

I would say close it using the OT close reason*

> - Questions must **demonstrate a minimal understanding** of the problem being solved. Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it should work. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist

With special emphasize on the *what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it should work* part.

Think about it: these people are basically asking, 'If I add one and nine, what do I get?'  Those people don't have the *what you've tried and why it didn't work* part.

<sub><sup>Your example could be migrated to SU/F, but that's another topic.</sup></sub>

Answer (score 0):

Let us not forget that there is one rare condition where I think these kinds of questions could be valid. It might be that what the OP is doing, is possibly dangerous, but this is the only way out.

I don't remember the exact question, but someone's git repository history became corrupt. 
The OP had found some blog post which suggested a way out. The question was asked if the running that particular command would restore the history. Some Git guru then answered that it was missing some parameter, and if the parameter had not been used (i.e. the command used as in the blog), It would have deleted the complete history.

In Most cases, the person asking the question, might feel that some cross checking is necessary, and might ask the question as a way of getting a second opinion. In most cases, that kind of caution is not necessary, but in some rare instances, it might help.